# How do I post data into the Facebook wall without login-dialogbox?

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on an Android app where we enter some text in edit box. All I want to do is simply send the text which typed (i.e. `edittext.gettext()`) to Facebook as my status. The important thing is I don't want a Facebook dialog box to pop up, instead, just send the message as status without a dialog box. Is there any way I could post without a dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is use full to you,

```
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);   


mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

And still if your problem exists because of an existing Facebook app in the device, then you might have make the login compulsory.

In this piece of your code,

```
do this  

public void loginAndPostToWall(){
 facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS,-1, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

It should do the trick.